# More 'Pythonic' way to write asymmetric if-else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I write some code of this structure bellow.

```py
if ....:
    if ....:
        ....
else:
    ....
```

A short example

```py
if name in name_dict:
    info = name_dict['name'] ## <-- may be a more complicated function
    if info == '':
        info = input("Input your info: ")
else:
    info = input("Input your info: ")
```

---

It looks non-pythonic and `yapf` always false indent the code into:

```py
if ....:
    if ....:
        ....
    else:
        ....
```

---

I try to rewrite the code into this form:

```py
if .... and ....:
    ....
else:
    ....
```

In this way, the example above can be transform into:

```py
if (name in name_dict) and name_dict['name'] != '':
    info = name_dict['name'] 
else:
    info = input("Input your info: ")
```

But in the rewritten code will execute the function `name_dict['name']` twice, thus it is not a efficient solutions.

I wonder is there any pythonic way to rewrite this code block, without in creasing the complexity.

Comment: If yapf is breaking your code, I would suggest not using yapf.

Comment: `yapf` is clearly broken if it can't figure out even basic block indentation differences.

Comment: What do the tags vim and styles have to do with this?

Comment: Assuming the inconsistent use of `name` and `'name'` is an accident, this looks like a job for `dict.get`, but the "may be a more complicated function" sounds like you're going to follow up with "but in my *real* code, ...", and we're not going to get to your actual problem for a while.

Comment: I think it is a general problem, and I don't known why you vote it down.

Comment: Just going to be real here. Stop worrying SO much about syntax that it kills you. If you aren't able to show us the actual code you're trying to fix here, I honestly don't think there's any need to change what you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure this out finally. **Assignment Expressions** in Python 3.8 is what I am looking for.

```py
if name in name_dict:
    info = name_dict['name'] ## <-- may be a more complicated function
    if info == '':
        info = input("Input your info: ")
else:
    info = input("Input your info: ")
```

Can be turn into:

```py
if (name not in name_dict) or (name in name_dict and (info := name_dict['name']) == ''):
    info = input("Input your info: ")
```

It is like expressing the logic in natural language. 'If name is not in name dictionary, or the info of name in name dictionary is empty, please input some info.'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.get()` here:

```
if name_dict.get(name):
    info = name_dict['name'] 
else:
    info = input("Input your info: ")
```

`name_dict.get(name)` will only be true if `name` exists as a key in `name_dict`, *and* the value associated with the key is not an empty value (`''` is false in a boolean context, if `name` is missing `None` is returned, which is also a false value).

These two lines can be combined with `or`, eliminating the `if` statement altogether:

```
info = name_dict.get(name) or input("Input your info: ")
```

That's because `or` short-circuits. If `name_dict.get(name)` produces a non-empty value, the `input()` function will not be called.

Comment: the dictionary  is trying to simplify the example, the real case should be more complicated.  This is not a general solution.

Comment: @ChangYe: there is no general solution. How you can collapse your tests *depends on the context*.